# drew's autoSuggest plugin help with AJAX results not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i use drew's autoSuggest plugin for some time but up until now I have hard coded my data into my JS, I'm trying to see if I can use AJAX to return the JSON data and query data like that. I seem to have it working but no matter what I try I can't get the results to be shown in the drop down UL it creates via jquery.

The JSON comes back as it should. This is my PHP code:

```
$input = $_GET["q"];
    $data = array();
    // query your DataBase here looking for a match to $input
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `state`, `idStates` FROM `states_list` WHERE (`state` LIKE '%{$input}%' OR `abbr` LIKE '%{$input}%')");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $json = array();
        $json['value'] = $row['idStates'];
        $json['name'] = $row['state'];
        $data[] = $json;
    }
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($data);
```

and my JS:

```
$('#state').autoSuggest('resources/ajax/suggest.php', {matchCase: true, minChars: 2, startText: '', emptyText: '', retrieveComplete: function(data){ console.log(data.value) }});
```

I have been trying to debug so I added the retrieveComplete parameter in there for that.

the PHP returns the AJAX with the JSON content...now just to figure out how to get the JS to pick it up append it to the UL LI

UPDATE:

I appened the data to a test div and its returning

```
results:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So If I get this right you get a respons that you store in the variable "results"?

I assume that these objects each contains a set of key/value pairs. Or maybe nested objects? It would be nice if you posted the response. You can do that by open up Firebug in Firefox (if you got that add on installed). Under "console" you will see the server response. Open it and you will see 4 tabs. Open the tab called JSON. Right click it an select "Copy Response Body". Then paste it in here.

There are a few ways to approach this. This is one of them:

```
var liStr = '',
    $yourUl = $('#id-of-your-ul');

// Assuming the response object is stored in the variable data
for (key in data) {
  liStr += '<li>Your key: ' + key + ', Your key value: ' + data[key] + '</li>';
}

$yourUl.append($(liStr));
```

Without being able to test it, I think it might work. Of course depending on what your response looks like. Try it and let me know.

Comment: my response is this when returned in firebug btwe {value: 'WY', name: 'Wyoming'}

Comment: Oh I see. So then I need to change my response above. Just a sec.

Comment: no its ok i was able to get what i needed by calling out obj.name in the output section. Im still not getting the results I need, I just think there is a bug with the plugin and jquery 1.4.4 or something along those lines that isn't letting me grad the JSON data and automatically get inserted into the UL. This is the site for the plugin as an example url :http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin/